# Hot to create subtask to multiple issue in Redmine?

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I am using Redmine 1.4 and I would like to add to a set of issues the same subtask to all of them.

For example, I have 10 new bugs, I would like to add the subtask "Check issue" and the subtask "Fix the issue" to all of them.

Is there any plugin or technique that helps me to do that?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use subtasks to manage a standard workflow.  I can see the appeal of that because then you could assign each step to a different person.  However, it sounds very complex to me -- I'd be surprised to find any options or plugins that do this.

You might find more success using statuses, rather than subtasks, to impose a structured workflow.

Comment: I understand your suggestion, but the states I would like to add are parallel and distributed between different people in the team. I have tried to implement them with a status workflow, but it doesn't fit my needs. I wonder why it is not possible to massively add subtasks to a selection of tasks! :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can use Bulk Edit to close multiple Issues.

Select all issues you want to change the status from issues list (Check box)

[image]

Select edit from AJAX menu and you can choose the status & update multiple records at once

[image]

Thanks

For more details you can visit...

http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/7908

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't seems to help to fix my problem. With that feature it is not possible to add the same subtask to the issues selected.